# setListAdapter method is not working with TabActivity

Tags: java, android, tabactivity

I have a TabActivity with 3 tabs, one of them has a ListActivity.
here is my problem, with the method setListAdapter i cant click on the other two tabs anymore. i dont know why. is there a way to solve this problem?

```
public class second extends ListActivity {
  SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;

  static final int MENU_NEW_KFZ = 0;

  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(HelloTab.MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

      Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, model FROM " + HelloTab.MY_DB_TABLE + ";", null);        
        startManagingCursor(c);    

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                c,
                new String[] { "_id" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });


      adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor theCursor, int column) {

                String ColumnName = theCursor.getString(1); //Name
                String ColumnModel = theCursor.getString(2); //Model

                ((TextView)view).setText(ColumnName + ", " + ColumnModel);

                return true;
            }
        });
     setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try these `af.notifyDataSetChanged();` where `af` is your adpater hope it helped.